# iPhone programming:Send message from one App to another App Via Bluetooth/Wi-Fi?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am new to iPhone development. I want to create an iPhone application, using which user can send message to another user who is using the same App through Bluetooth/Wi-Fi. I want to know how can i send a message into another iPhone via Bluetooth/Wi-Fi? I want to know the technology which i should use to sending such thing from one iPhone to another through Bluetooth/Wi-Fi.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Game Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html). Check this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) by apple.

Comment: ya,can u elaborate it?how can i use Wi-fi?

Comment: checke the linked references.. it is clearly illustrated there... also see the sample codes provided by apple @ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=GameKit